# Reporting a count in 2 different tables

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working in a Crystal Report that someone else created.  In the report I want to count the total number of days someone is absent.  The statement below is what is currently in place.
(select count(*) from attend_day inner join absencetype on name=attend_type
where GRP='Absent')
However it isn't giving me the correct number.  it gives me some outrages number like 1,500.  The table I'm working with are Attendance Table.
In the Attendance Table there is ATTEND_TYPE which is Attendance entry for the student and I want to total the number of days that have the word Absent in them.  There are 2 values Absent - Excused and Absent - Unexcused.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide your code snippet.  Be sure to tag code within your post so that it is differentiated from the rest of the body text.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a formula called "Absent":

```
iif(Attendance.ATTEND_TYPE like "*absent*", 1, 0)
```

Then insert a summary that takes the SUM of @Absent